# Chartist.js - Add add tick marks (not values) to Y-axis

Tags: javascript, svg

I am looking for a way to add actual tick marks, small lines, that point to the value on the Y-axis, as in this pic:
[image: screen-shot-tick-marks]

I have tried appending a path to the '.ct-vertical' lines (except for axis lines themselves) and though they are appended in the code, they are not visible. I'm also not sure if it's best if they are added to the y-axis at each value, or appended as extensions to the '.ct-vertical' lines, which I have tried per above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try add ::before for the span)

```
span.ct-label.ct-horizontal {
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: relative;

 &::before {  
    content: "|";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
    left: 0px;
    font-size: 5px;
   font-weight: bold;
   color: black;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/duchuy-the-flexboxer/pen/WWjreW

(for IE you need to target <text> element though)